# Android repeat alarm manager in not triggering immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

My code:

```
Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calSet.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
```

and say, I'm executing at 11:30. Alarm triggers immediately (which is expected).
But, for the same when I use

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calSet.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pi);
```

alarm is not triggered immediately. There is a delay up to 1 minute (which is not expected).
I want repeating alarm to trigger immediately without any delay.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: WILD GUESS: you are targetting **API Level 19+**

Comment: @Der Golem minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: You see? I was right - this is why I use targetSdkVersion **18**.

Comment: i guess the answer that you are looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438405/android-alarm-working-but-delayed check it out

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie : I have updated the code to reset both 'sec' and 'milliseconds' but, still not working. There is a delay.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html: `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.`

Comment: @DerGolem: As you said, it is working perfectly when I set targetSdkVersion to 18. Suppose, If I build my application with targetSdk version to 18 will it create any problem when it installed on higher API (>18) android devices?

Comment: No problem at all, why it should? If so, old apps created targetting API Level 14 shouldn't run on newer devices... but they do, since Android is **backwards compatible**.

Comment: @DerGolem: I usually target latest version. So, I asked. Thanks a lot :-). If you post your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Not everyone will like my answer. Many are **fashion-followers**, so they are **concerned with Material Design**. I risk a lot of downvotes, if posting such an answer. @hqt answer is correct (+1), so you can accept **his** answer, instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code to :

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
} else {
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

**@Edit**
Above code will work for set exactly time. But this section will explain about repeating for alarm manager.

For api below 19, we use `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` will make alarms trigger exactly at specified time periodically. But from 19 and newer, this method won't work again and there aren't any apis support this behavior. I think this api change make developers thinking more carefully when they create a timer. Because a timer trigger at exactly time periodically will drain battery so much.

If you want you must do on your own. Firstly, you set `AlarmManager.setExact()` and when alarm trigger, you will make alarm trigger again next time **manually**

Here is the code:

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     alarmManager. setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
} else {
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

And in your intent, where you put handle code, you should check if android api >= 19, application will create new alarm for the next event.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
         doSomething();
         // calculate time for next event
         Calendar nextEvent = calcNextEvent();
         // and set alarm again
         alarmManager. setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextEvent.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
 } else {
         doSomething();
 }
```

I think this is problem in android api design. Old code should work on newer version. Anyway, this new api design make everything clearer for developer, better for system(save battery). Of course, when you use new api :)

Hope this help :)

Comment: I guess, this is not a repeating Alarm. I'm looking for repeat alarm.

Comment: @Ravindra I have edited my post. you can see again :) Basically, from API >= 19. you must do this manually

Comment: @hqt I did the repeating exactly as you wrote here, the problem i'm getting is that my broadcast receiver gets called about 10-30 times (seems random) on my lollipop device. It uses setExact to trigger the alarm, and when it triggers it is doing setExact again (which should happen after 1 day, but it gets called 10-30 times immediately). Do you know what can be the reason? Can you help me here? Thanks