# remove data after 48 hours at 12 in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

i want to delete the records from database after 48 hours at 12 PM night each time , i have set the alarm as follows , but its not getting fire at all, what i am doing wrong ?

```
dayAlarmMgr= (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alramIntent = new Intent(this,SyncAlaram.class);         
        alramIntent.setAction(SyncAlaram.WIPE_REPORT_DATA);
        dayAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alramIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,  12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        dayAlarmMgr.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2, 
                dayAlarmIntent);
```

details

```
Platform Android 4.0 and above 

android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Comment: on what o.s. device are you trying this? and what is the api target, min for your app,  [alarm manager triggering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766732/android-repeat-alarm-manager-in-not-triggering-immediately)

Comment: view the edits please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot comment, I post an answer instead. Try this:

```
dayAlarmMgr.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2, 
            dayAlarmIntent);
```

Notice that you use absolute time, replace`AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` with `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`. `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` means time since device booted rather than the UTC time.

Comment: would this alarm gets fire even after i restart my phone ?

Comment: No, you should set the alarm again when device reboots.

Comment: but the issue is `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` not getting fired at all

Comment: Have you declared `<uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` in Manifest?