# How can I make this Alarm Clock app. to be able to set alarm at any time of the day and exactly at that time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alarms

I am new to android development and have very little knowledge in java and I have seen this Alarm Clock app tutorial in the internet. The application has problems. It can't set time before the current time of phone and it doesn't start at the exact time. How to make this application so it can set alarm within 24 hours and at the exact time?

AlarmActivity.java

```
package com.javapapers.androidalarmclock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
private static AlarmActivity inst;
private TextView alarmTextView;

public static AlarmActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
    alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
    ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton)     findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,   alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        setAlarmText("");
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
    }
}

public void setAlarmText(String alarmText) {
    alarmTextView.setText(alarmText);
}
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.javapapers.androidalarmclock;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //this will update the UI with message
    AlarmActivity inst = AlarmActivity.instance();
    inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

    //this will sound the alarm tone
    //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
    //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

    //this will send a notification message
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

AlarmService.java

```
package com.javapapers.androidalarmclock;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new   NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);


    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
}
```

Please Help! I am desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a 24hour span, you also need to set the day, that's why you can't set the time before the current time of the phone.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
       calendar.add(Calendar.DAY, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, the alarm doesn't just start when I set it before the current time of the phone. I change the DAY to DAY_OF_WEEK because DAY gives an error "DAY cannot be resolve or is not a field. Would that change anything? This just my guess but the your additional code let's me cover Today and Tomorrow to be able to set an alarm? Plus, additional question, The alarm doesn't start at the exact time, how do I fix that?

Comment: The most safe bet would be then 
`long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if(time < System.currentTimeMillis()) calendar.setTimeInMillis(time + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));`
Because I'm not quite sure what happens if you increment Saturday, does it go from Sunday or does an error occur.
This should cover you for 24h span, so for example from 8pm today to 8pm tomorrow.
What exactly do you mean by exact time? How much is the diff from the desired time and the actual notification time?

Comment: Example, I set the alarm for 7:00 am. But when the phone time hits 7:00 am, its still doesn't starts. It has a delay of a couple of second or even a minute at most I think. I know it is just a couple of seconds of delay but I still want to fix it.

Comment: Connect the phone to the computer and check if you have the desired notifications set up at the correct time with terminal: `adb shell dumpsys notification > ~/notifications.txt` and open the `notifications.txt` file

Comment: ahaha, I am sorry, but that answer is too complicated for me. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: No problem, I remember when I had the same problem, but I really forgot what I did back then :/ Try checking other posts, I believe this is a known problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20438452/6873402

I would just like to share this answer that I found about the Delay Problem in the Alarm Clock